# What will be better: click counter on mysql or on flat file?

Tags: php, mysql, file, counter

I always was sure it is better and faster to use flat files to store realtime visit/click counter data: open file in append mode, lock it, put data and then close. Then read this file by crontab once in a five minutes, store contents to DB and truncate file for new data. 
But today my friend told me, that it is a wrong way. It will better to have a permanent MySql connection and write data right to DB on every click. First, DB can store results to memory table. Second, even we store to a table located on disk, then this file is permanently opened by it, so no need to find it on disk and open again and again on every query.

What do you think about it?

UPD: We talking about high-traffic sites, about million per day.

Comment: This can get very tricky, especially for high-traffic websites. I've never actually written quite what you're describing, but I'd probably go with logging requests to a database, and counting them on a regular basis. Then store the result of the counting in another table (for example `CREATE TABLE countings ( weeknr TINYINT, year SMALLINT, viewcount INT );`) and deleting the counted rows.

Comment: I would use [INSERT DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html) or mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is right. Write to a file and then a cronjob sending to database every 5 minutes? That sounds very convoluted. I can't imagine a good reason for not writing directly to DB.

Also, when you write to a file in the way you described, the operations are serialized. A user will have to wait for the other one to release the lock before writing. That simply won't scale if you ever need it. The same will happen with a DB if you always write to the same row, but you can have multiple rows for the same value, write to a random one and sum them when you need the total.

It doesn't make much sense to use a memory table in this case. If your data doesn't need to be persisted, it's much simpler to use a memcache you probably already have somewhere and simply increment the value for the key.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a database WITHOUT transactions, you will get the same underlying performance as using files with more reliability and less coding.

It could be true that writing to a database is heavy - e.g. the DB could be on a different server so you have network traffic, or it could be a transactional DB in which case every write has at least 2 writes (potentially more if indexes are involved), but if you're aware of all this stuff then you can use a DB, take advantage of decades of work by others and make your programming task easy.